# What's the easiest way to duplicate a column?

Tags: php, oracle, duplicates

Currently, I'm getting the ID of the column via a select statement and insert all the returned values (except the ID).

Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: @skaffman: did you write anything?

Comment: he edited your tags. I don't know Oracle one bit, but isn't there an equivalent to `INSERT INTO TABLENAME select * FROM tablename WHERE id = x`?

Comment: thanks for your reply...let me try it out.

Comment: worked! thank you very much! this is soooo much faster!

Comment: you're welcome. I'm adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Oracle one bit, but there should be an equivalent to

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME select * FROM tablename WHERE id = x
```

Comment: That will work in Oracle as written, assuming it doesn't violate a primary or unique constraint.